# Use a scope variable inside .success and .error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to use a scope variable $scope.field.name when a request is done or failed. I tried to console it but it says undefined. How can I access a scope variable inside these syntax?

```
usiApp.controller('fieldController',['$scope','$window','$http','field','$timeout','Profile','Referrence',function ($scope,$window,$http,field,$timeout,Profile,Referrence)
{
$scope.DoSomething = function(){
  $scope.field.class = 'fieldController'; //class of php method
  $scope.field.method = 'DoSomething'; //name of php method
  $scope.field.name = 'Ellsworth';
  field.getdata($scope.field)
      .success(function(data){
          if (data == true) {
              console.log($scope.field.name); //returns error this is the problem
          } else {
              console.log($scope.field.name); //returns error
          }
      })
      .error(function(data, status) {
          $scope.messages = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
          console.log($scope.status);
          console.log($scope.messages);
          console.log($scope.field.name); //returns error
      });
}
}
```

My field.getdata service function:

```
usiServices.factory('field', function($http) {
return {
    getdata : function(option) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'php/field-route.php',
            headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: $.param(option)
        });
      },
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please add the full code, specially the method: field.getdata

Comment: What is the variable `field` here?

Comment: already added the field.getdata

Comment: Add full controller code. Have you injected 'field' factory?

Comment: added controller code

Comment: If you log `field`, what is returned?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Acyn1 (return of field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `$scope.field = {};`.The line will create an empty object. After creating the object, then you can create property of the object(`$scope.field.class, $scope.field.method,$scope.field.name`). As the object is not created, you are getting the undefined error.
Add this `$scope.field = {};` line before the following:

```
  $scope.field.class = 'fieldController'; //class of php method
  $scope.field.method = 'DoSomething'; //name of php method
  $scope.field.name = 'Ellsworth';
```

So, the final updated lines will be as follows:

```
  $scope.field = {};
  $scope.field.class = 'fieldController'; //class of php method
  $scope.field.method = 'DoSomething'; //name of php method
  $scope.field.name = 'Ellsworth';
```

Comment: TypeError: $scope.field.getdata is not a function

Comment: check the answer.

Comment: my problem is between these lines .success(function(data){
          if (data == true) {
              console.log($scope.field.name); //returns error
          } else {
              console.log($scope.field.name); //returns error
          }
      })

Comment: i want to use $scope.field.name inside the .success function.

Comment: yes. its because $scope.field object is undefined. with the $scope.field = {}; I created the object. Its shorthand for object creation.

Comment: Adding $scope.field = {}; erases all the existing scopes im using

Comment: It will not erase the scope, it will erase $scope.field variable and the $scope.field = {} is the first statement, how it will erase.